# Remove dust from new garage

Tags: floor, garage

We have a brand new garage and are about to put a painted floor down. It needs to be totally clear of dust. I am not sure whether to hire a dry industrial cleaner or a wet/dry one?

Answer (score 1):

If it hasn't seen a lot of foot or car traffic yet, you can just sweep/vac to get it clean enough for the floor paint.  If it has any grime on it, then mopping and sucking up the water with a shop vac is the way to go.